# Decompressing a zipfile into memory stream - C#

Tags: c#

I have written code to store the encoded string of zip file into temp path and now I want to store the encoded zipfile string to memorystream instead of temp path. Can someone please help me how to read the stream and pass it as a string to ZipFile class...I am using DOTNETZIP library to unpack password protested file.
Please see below my code.

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();                        

foreach (ActivityMimeAttachment a in attachments.Entities)
{
    if (a.FileName.EndsWith(".zip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        string strcontent = a.Body;

        byte[] filecontent = Convert.FromBase64String(strcontent); // unpack the base-64 to a blob      

        File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath + a.FileName, filecontent); // Working code creates a zip file           
        string attachmentfile = tempPath + a.FileName;                                

            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(attachmentfile))
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip.Entries)
                {

                    if ((entry.FileName.EndsWith(".xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
                        (entry.FileName.EndsWith(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                    {                                                
                        entry.ExtractWithPassword(tempPath, "password");

                        FileStream inFile;
                        byte[] binaryData;
                        string file = tempPath + entry.FileName;

                        inFile = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        binaryData = new Byte[inFile.Length];
                        long bytesRead = inFile.Read(binaryData, 0,
                                             (int)inFile.Length);
                        inFile.Close();
```

Comment: Can you not just convert your byte array to a memory stream? Stream stream = new MemoryStream(filecontent);

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, you are right. I can convert but my problem here is how to read it back from memory stream and pass it as a string to ZIP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to convert your file content to a memory stream (`Stream filestream = new MemoryStream(filecontent)`) then use `ZipFile.Read(fileStream)`. Then use a `StreamReader` to get the contents out as a string. So try something like this (note it's untested):

```
string myString;
byte[] filecontent = Convert.FromBase64String(strcontent);
using (var filestream = new MemoryStream(filecontent))
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(filestream))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            if ((entry.FileName.EndsWith(".xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
                (entry.FileName.EndsWith(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    entry.ExtractWithPassword(ms, "password");

                    ms.Position = 0;
                    var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                    myString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                ...
```

If the results should be a base64 string, do this:

```
                    entry.ExtractWithPassword(ms, "password");

                    ms.Position = 0;
                    myString = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
```

You may or may not have to reset the stream position, but it's good practice to.

Now you can use the results as a string without having to write to a file first.

Comment: Thanks a lot - Balah. Exactly what I need and a small question the string where I am storing the data is not Base 64 soI tried to add a line.. But I am getting Out of memory when I try opening PDF file.                                `var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
string attachmentContent = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);`

Comment: You're welcome. If you want it as base64, then remove the last 2 lines and put `myString = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())`. Answer will be updated

Comment: That's amazing. It's working. I really thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: I tried the code but there was an error saying that:
'ZipFile' does not contain definition for 'read'

Comment: @scar the op was using DotNetZip and that has `ZipFile.Read()`. Not to be confused with the ZipFile class that now comes with .NET - that class does not have Read().